# Trouble running Protractor tests using Selenium Server

Tags: node.js, windows, google-chrome, selenium, protractor

### Trying to run Protractor/Jasmine/Selenium e2e tests

Trying to run e2e tests using Protractor using the stand alone Selenium server and the chrome driver.

I get the following Selenium server error when I try to run my test using Protractor:
    14:08:24.188 WARN - Exception: C:\Users\ARM678\AppData\Local\Temp\jna--1409357381\jna1939368593138214681.dll: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Here are some details...

I start Selenium stand alone server by executing at the command line as follows (passing in the chrome web driver location):

### Command

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\TDAWare\servers\selenium\drivers\chromedriver.exe"
```

### Output (Looks Good So Far):

```
14:00:27.695 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server
Setting system property webdriver.chrome.driver to C:\TDAWare\servers\selenium\drivers\chromedriver.exe
14:00:27.845 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 25.72-b15
14:00:27.846 INFO - OS: Windows 7 6.1 x86
14:00:27.855 INFO - v2.52.0, with Core v2.52.0. Built from revision 4c2593c
14:00:27.918 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
14:00:27.918 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not registered
14:00:27.925 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver registration is skipped:
registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=safari, version=, platform=MAC}] does not match the current platform VISTA
14:00:28.100 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
14:00:28.100 INFO - Selenium Server is up and running
```

### Protractor conf.js file:

```
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['tdau-homepage-spec.js'],
  allScriptsTimeout: 200000,
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 200000,
        showColors: true,
    print: function() {}
  },
  onPrepare: function() {
      var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');
      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({displayStacktrace: 'all'}));
   }
}
```

### Protractor tdau-homepage-spec.js

```
'use strict';
describe('My first test suite', function() {
    it('should bring up a web page', function() {
        browser.get('https://internal.tdameritradeu.com/dist');
        expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('TD Ameritrade U');
    });
});
```

### Run Test (Everything breaks):

```
protractor conf.js
```

I get the following 2 stack traces. The first is from the Selenium Server. The second is from protractor.

From Selenium Server:

```
14:08:22.142 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName=chrome, platform=WINDOWS}]])
14:08:22.154 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{count=1, browserName=chrome, platform=WINDOWS}]
Starting ChromeDriver 2.16.333243 (0bfa1d3575fc1044244f21ddb82bf870944ef961) on port 38568
Only local connections are allowed.
14:08:24.161 WARN - Exception thrown
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593c', time: '2016-02-11 19:06:42'
System info: host: 'ILOL-F8VN662', ip: '10.20.102.66', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_72'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:183)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.<init>(DefaultSession.java:119)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.createSession(DefaultSession.java:95)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverSessions.newSession(DefaultDriverSessions.java:124)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:59)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:1)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.rest.ResultConfig.handle(ResultConfig.java:111)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.JsonHttpCommandHandler.handleRequest(JsonHttpCommandHandler.java:79)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.handleRequest(DriverServlet.java:202)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:164)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.service(DriverServlet.java:130)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:428)
        at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.dispatch(ServletHandler.java:680)
        at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:571)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1526)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1479)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer.service(HttpServer.java:920)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.service(HttpConnection.java:820)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handleNext(HttpConnection.java:986)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:837)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener.handleConnection(SocketListener.java:243)
        at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadedServer.handle(ThreadedServer.java:358)
        at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:537)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593c', time: '2016-02-11 19:06:42'
System info: host: 'ILOL-F8VN662', ip: '10.20.102.66', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_72'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.callConstructor(DefaultDriverProvider.java:113)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.newInstance(DefaultDriverProvider.java:97)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance(DefaultDriverFactory.java:60)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:222)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.callConstructor(DefaultDriverProvider.java:103)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\ARM678\AppData\Local\Temp\jna--1409357381\jna1939368593138214681.dll: %1 is not a valid Win32 application
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:761)
        at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:736)
        at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:131)
        at org.openqa.selenium.os.Kernel32.<clinit>(Kernel32.java:34)
        at org.openqa.selenium.os.ProcessUtils.killWinProcess(ProcessUtils.java:133)
        at org.openqa.selenium.os.ProcessUtils.killProcess(ProcessUtils.java:81)
        at org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog.destroyHarder(UnixProcess.java:247)
        at org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog.access$2(UnixProcess.java:246)
        at org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess.destroy(UnixProcess.java:125)
        at org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.destroy(CommandLine.java:155)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.stop(DriverService.java:196)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:94)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:644)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:701)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.quit(RemoteWebDriver.java:526)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:134)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:170)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:138)
        ... 14 more
14:08:24.188 WARN - Exception: C:\Users\ARM678\AppData\Local\Temp\jna--1409357381\jna1939368593138214681.dll: %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

From Protractor I get the following Stack Trace:

```
λ protractor conf.js
Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver

C:\TDAWare\servers\node\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\error.js:108
  var template = new Error(this.message);
                 ^
UnknownError: C:\Users\ARM678\AppData\Local\Temp\jna--1409357381\jna1939368593138214681.dll: %1 is not a valid Win32 application
    at new bot.Error (C:\TDAWare\servers\node\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\error.js:108:18)
    at Object.bot.response.checkResponse (C:\TDAWare\servers\node\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\response.js:109:9)
    at C:\TDAWare\servers\node\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:160:24
    at [object Object].promise.Promise.goog.defineClass.invokeCallback_ (C:/TDAWare/servers/node/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:1337:14)
    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.goog.defineClass.goog.defineClass.abort_.error.executeNext_.execute_ (C:/TDAWare/servers/node/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:2776:14)
    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.goog.defineClass.goog.defineClass.abort_.error.executeNext_ (C:/TDAWare/servers/node/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:2758:21)
    at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (C:\TDAWare\servers\node\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:124:15)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:368:9)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.acquireSession_ (C:\TDAWare\servers\node\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:157:22)
    at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.createSession (C:\TDAWare\servers\node\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:131:30)
    at [object Object].Builder.build (C:\TDAWare\servers\node\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\builder.js:445:22)
    at [object Object].DriverProvider.getNewDriver (C:\TDAWare\servers\node\node_modules\protractor\lib\driverProviders\driverProvider.js:42:27)
    at [object Object].Runner.createBrowser (C:\TDAWare\servers\node\node_modules\protractor\lib\runner.js:190:37)
    at C:\TDAWare\servers\node\node_modules\protractor\lib\runner.js:280:21
    at _fulfilled (C:\TDAWare\servers\node\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\TDAWare\servers\node\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\TDAWare\servers\node\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    at C:\TDAWare\servers\node\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:556:49
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
```

### My Thoughts...

I believe the root cause of the issue can be found in the Selenium stack trace when it says that

```
14:08:24.188 WARN - Exception: C:\Users\ARM678\AppData\Local\Temp\jna--1409357381\jna1939368593138214681.dll: %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

I think that when it tries to utilize the chromedriver.exe, the chrome driver creates a dll file called jna1939368593138214681.dll and for some reason Windows doesn't like that file [a brilliant piece of deduction seeing that's exactly what the error says]

### What I've tried:

- I have tried re-downloading the driver to make sure the download
  didn't corrupt the zip file
- I have tried different versions of the driver.
- I have tried unzipping the driver zip file with 2 different
  zip utilities (winzip and winrar) to make sure the unzipping process
  didn't corrupt anything

### Environment

- OS: Windows 7 Enterprise
- Type: 64 bit
- chromedriver version: 2.21 (also tried v.2.16)
- node version: 4.2.4
- npm version: 3.7.5

*Note* - Google explicitly states that chrome only has a 32-bit version of the driver and states that 64-bit systems will work with the 32-bit driver and that there is no 64-bit driver available.

Comment: Can't help but can't u run it in a Linux VM to avoid good old windows issues?

Comment: Unfortunately we are in a tightly locked down environment so it's not an option.

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration file is missing `capabilities`. You will need to tell protractor which driver to use: `browserName: 'chrome'`.

```
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome'
  },
  specs: ['tdau-homepage-spec.js'],
  allScriptsTimeout: 200000,
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 200000,
        showColors: true,
    print: function() {}
  },
  onPrepare: function() {
      var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');
      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({displayStacktrace: 'all'}));
   }
}
```

Comment: First - thank you for the idea and for taking the time to respond. However, if you look at Protractor's referenceConf.js, if you don't include the capabilities section it defaults to chrome. I have tried adding it and it makes no difference.

Comment: What version of Chrome is this? There was a similar issue in protractor...
See: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1424

You could also run your chromedriver directly:
chromedriver.exe --log-path=chromedriver.log --verbose
See: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/702

Does it work in Firefox? Or is this failure only in Chrome?

Comment: Thank you for the response...the issue still persists and I've had to do a ton of workarounds and techno-gymnastics to get this semi-working. The version of chrome is: 35.0.1916.114. In firefox, it gets further and executes the test but always throws up an exception regardless if the test passes or fails. Again...thank you for the response.

Comment: Have you tried this recently with the latest 4.0.11?